# AJAX POST ---> Unidetified index?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im looking to fix following AJAX POST method:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php echo($_POST['send']);?>
   </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'index.php', // both files are in root level
   data: {send: "string"}
});
```

In dev tool's network tab every request seems to be in right order and the response shows "string" is included in the body. The question is: Why I'm getting: "Undefined index: send"??

[image: Screenshot of dev console]

I'm using Apache/2.4.37 (x64) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12, jQuery/3.3.1 (just in case there has been some syntax updates, which I'm not aware of).

Comment: I don't undersatand what you want to acheive. If you want to avoid this error you should write `<?php if(isset($_POST['send'])){ echo($_POST['send']); } ?>`

Comment: During which process you are calling ajax

Comment: try adding `dataType:'json'` in ajax

Comment: Because there is no POST data when you load `index.php` with your browser (and without coming from a form).

Comment: `<?= (isset($_POST['send']))?$_POST['send']:''; ?>`

Comment: What do you do with the request? The request is asynchronous, it asks for data to the same file, but a new instance of it. If your intent is to set data in the same window you have open, you don't use ajax.

Comment: @911madza small point, [echo is not a function, it is a language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) - the consequences of that are it doesn't need parentheses. @Roy that can be `<?= $_POST['send'] ?? '' ?>`

Comment: @Roy for PHP 7+ `<?= $_POST['send'] ?? ''; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the order of events:

1. You type the URL into the address bar which causes the browser to make a GET request to `index.php`
2. This runs the PHP which gives the browser an instruction to load two scripts, and an error message because it was a GET request so `$_POST['send']` is not set
3. The JavaScript causes the browser to make a **second** request to the same URL, this time it is a POST request.
4. The PHP runs again and gives different output (the script elements and the echoed input).
5. The browser makes the second response available to your JavaScript. jQuery processes it, but then it falls out of scope and is discarded because you have no `done()` handler.

You should rewrite your code so you have **two** different URLs.

- One URL should be for the HTML document
- One URL should be for the web service which you access with JavaScript

You could also use one URL and an `if/else` based on if the request is POST or GET, but that wouldn't be [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) or a sensible [seperation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

---

Note that your code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin makes sense! that's a nice answer with detailed description on requests and responses, thank you! any code examples on how to achieve your recommended approach with two different URLs?

Comment: @911madza Example: create a page `ajax.php` which returns `$_POST['send']` (with `echo` or `return`). In your ajax call, option `url` have to be `ajax.php`. In your html of `index.php`, remove the php. Add a `success` callback which appends the returned result into your DOM. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more information.

Comment: @iArcadia this method appends the value to DOM elements, but i need to set it to php variable in index.php, so i can use it later in php code (i need to create $var = "string"  <-  this is the value passed by ajax)

Comment: @911madza Well, you can save your send data in `$_SESSION` if you want to use it later without the need to make a AJAX call for each page?

Comment: @iArcadia i've came across two other working methods: 1) to store the value in cookies and access them via php later; 2) adding the value to url with name=value and access via php, but those solutions seem messy to me

Comment: @iArcadia you mean smth like sessionStorage.setItem("string","sessionName");?

Comment: @911madza Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.session.php) for using `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

This is also the page which you loaded in the GET requests visible in developer tools ?
You are loading it as a GET with no POST parameters - thats why it is undefined, but when you send correct POST request it echoes correct data. If u just want to fix this error, in other word display $_POST['send'] only on POST request do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php if(!empty($_POST)) echo($_POST['send']);?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Edit: this will only check if its $_POST request, not necesarily if 'send' is set. For that use

```
if(!empty($_POST['send']))
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that `$_POST['send']` is set.

Comment: @Script47 it doesnt, but it checks if its POST request and the error wont show on GET request. This may or may not be good solution depending on he is trying to do.